# What is the name of that crimp?

Tags: connector, identification, crimp

We are working on a hoverboard. It has a Hall sensor with 5 wires and this weird connector. I can't find its name and the hoverboard has no documentation with its BOM.

Has anyone already seen it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are crimps from JST. More exactly it is the model [5 pin JST SM 2.5mm](http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eSM.pdf)